# Convert.ToDouble exception: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, exception, double

When i try to convert a number like 1.1 to a double i get thrown a exception: "Input string was not in a correct format." I don't know why this is happening since the input i give is correct and the variable where i am converting to is a double. Below is the code:

Controller create method:

```
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                Riskanalysis riskanalysis = new Riskanalysis()
                {
                    dateCreation = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["dateCreation"]),
                    userId = collection["userId"],
                    categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["categoryId"]),
                    zoneId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["zoneId"]),
                    equipmentId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["equipmentId"]),
                    taskId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["taskId"]),
                    activity = collection["activity"],
                    action = collection["action"],
                    descriptionPotentialRisk = collection["descriptionPotentialRisk"],
                    dangerId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["dangerId"]),
                    consequenceId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["consequenceId"]),
                    dangerousEnergiesId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["dangerousEnergiesId"]),
                    preventionMeasures = collection["preventionMeasures"],
                    safetyProcedures = collection["safetyProcedures"],
                    preSeriousness = Convert.ToDouble(collection["preSeriousness"]),
                    preProbability = Convert.ToDouble(collection["preProbability"]),
                    preExposure = Convert.ToDouble(collection["preExposure"]),
                    preRiskDegree = Convert.ToDouble(collection["preRiskDegree"]),
                    preRiskCategory = Convert.ToDouble(collection["preRiskCategory"]),
                };

                DanoneRiskanalysisManager rm = new DanoneRiskanalysisManager();
                rm.InsertRiskanalysis(riskanalysis);

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Input fields:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="preSeriousness" class="control-label">Pre seriousness:</label>
                    <input asp-for="preSeriousness" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="preSeriousness" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="preProbability" class="control-label">Pre probability:</label>
                    <input asp-for="preProbability" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="preProbability" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="preExposure" class="control-label">Pre exposure:</label>
                    <input asp-for="preExposure" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="preExposure" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="preRiskDegree" class="control-label">Pre risk degree:</label>
                    <input asp-for="preRiskDegree" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="preRiskDegree" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="preRiskCategory" class="control-label">Pre risk category:</label>
                    <input asp-for="preRiskCategory" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="preRiskCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

Anyone knows what the cause could be or where to look for?

Thanks already!

Comment: have you checked locale yet ?, probably the number format doesn't use "." As a decimal separator, try typing "," instead of "."

Comment: This fixed it, thanks alot! It's probably because i live in Belgium that they use "," instead of "."?

Comment: good to hear that locale `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` helps you in this case. Beside, I also have fallen to similar error while parsing object type like yours and due to larger  set it was almost difficult to track. Definitely I would like to suggest using `Double.TryParse` whenever required.

Comment: @henocsalinas You should put that as an answer and AVandijck will mark it as correct answer

Comment: Yea i was thinking about using Double.TryParse, but do i have to make an int variable for every input then or do i get this wrong?

Comment: I've already placed the comment as an answer @JerdineSabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked locale yet ?, probably the number format doesn't use "." As a decimal separator, try typing "," instead of "."

for more information see:
[support.microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306162/how-to-set-current-culture-programmatically-in-an-asp-net-application)