# C# - Double gets unwantedly converted to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to submit 3 doubles in a form while use C#. Whenever i input integers in the form everything works fine, but when i set doubles as the input they automatically are getting converted to null when i submit my form? I also dont see any exceptions getting caught..

Here's my controller code that i use:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(int? mainRiskanalysisId, int? categoryId, int? zoneId, int? equipmentId, int? taskId, 
        string activity, string action, string descriptionPotentialRisk, int? dangerId, int? consequenceId, 
        int? dangerousEnergiesId, string preventionMeasures, string safetyProcedures, double? preSeriousness,
        double? preProbability, double? preExposure, double? preRiskDegree, double? preRiskCategory, IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            Riskanalysis riskanalysis = new Riskanalysis()
            {
                mainRiskanalysisId = mainRiskanalysisId,
                categoryId = categoryId, 
                zoneId = zoneId, 
                equipmentId = equipmentId,
                taskId = taskId,
                activity = activity,
                action = action,
                descriptionPotentialRisk = descriptionPotentialRisk,
                dangerId = dangerId,
                consequenceId = consequenceId,
                dangerousEnergiesId = dangerousEnergiesId,
                preventionMeasures = preventionMeasures,
                safetyProcedures = safetyProcedures,
                preSeriousness = preSeriousness,
                preProbability = preProbability,
                preExposure = preExposure,
                preRiskDegree = preRiskDegree,
                preRiskCategory = preRiskCategory
            };


            _manager.InsertRiskanalysis(riskanalysis);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
        }
        catch (FormatException fe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fe.ToString());
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return null; 
    }
```

Here are my inputs i use for the doubles:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="preSeriousness" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="preSeriousness" id="preSeriousnessInput" class="form-control" type="text" />
                <span asp-validation-for="preSeriousness" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="preProbability" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="preProbability" id="preProbabilityInput" class="form-control" type="text" />
                <span asp-validation-for="preProbability" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="preExposure" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="preExposure" id="preExposureInput" class="form-control" type="text" />
                <span asp-validation-for="preExposure" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

The doubles i'm talking about are: preSeriouness, preProbability, preExposure.

Anyone has a clue of what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you try to use a comma instead of a dot to enter the decimal in your form?

Comment: When i try and do that, jquery validation tells me that its not a number. @JohnCaprez

Comment: Have you identified if the issue is in the front-end or in the back-end? Does the request from the browser look good?

Comment: When i check the netword tab in my browser the POST i'm doing is getting a 302 found status code and the GET is getting a 200 ok status? Anything else i need to look at? @devcrp

Comment: Well I was really talking about the request body sent from the browser, where those decimals are being sent. So that you check that the values for the decimals are the expected, just to discard the problem may be in the frontend

Comment: Ohh, yea the data in the body seems to be right so it should be a back-end issue.@devcrp

Comment: Disable jQuery validation to check if the issue is with the dot and comma. 
If MVC can't bind a posted value to a parameter it is null. As it is able to bind the value if you enter an integer the entire process of posting from the front end to the back end is working fine, its just not recognizing the double value as a double

Comment: Yea that seems like a good idea, i'm trying to disable jquery validation but no succes. Do you how i can disable it or disable it for a couple fields? @JohnCaprez

Comment: What if you try to just use postman to mock a POST request and be able to test different values?

Comment: I see you have asked about the same problem in a different post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486977/convert-todouble-exception-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format). I think the double you are entering is not valid.
Can you give us an example of a double value you enter?

Comment: Some doubles i tried are 0.1 or 0.5 or 1.1 for example? @JohnCaprez

Comment: Sorry to ask again; If you enter 0,1 or 0,5 it does not work either?

Comment: When i do that jquery validation tells me its not a number. My suspicion is that maybe jquery validation want a '.' seperator and mvc wants a ',' seperator?

Comment: Yes, that is what I suspect, hence why I wanted you to disable jQuery validation so you can send any value you want.
If it works with a comma then you have to set the "culture" on your server to match the one in your browser. The way to do that depends on what version of aspnet MVC you use.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Is actively swallowing Exceptions, without logging them. While it is one thing to not tell the user in a WebApplication the exception, also not logging them is a critical fault. You propably get an exception, you just went out of your way to hide it from yourself.

There are two articles on Exception handling. One is a classification, so you know [what to catch and what not to catch](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). The other is [general advice on handling and (re)throwing Exceptions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET).

I am confident that once you read through them and fixed cases like the above code, you get a Exception that will tell you exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm using Stackify Prefix to check if there are any exceptions thrown and i can't find any?

Comment: @A.Vandijck Compiler and JiT can propably skip Exceptions, if they **see** it wll be ignored. Easier to just jump into the catch.

Comment: Alright, i'll try to jump into the catch than. I'm pretty new to this, do you have any suggested exception i could catch?

Comment: @A.Vandijck Nope. Just remove that catch. Or *at least* put `e.ToString()` into a log, if you hit it. `catch (Exception e)` is it's a cardinal sin of Exception Handling. That you also do not log or expose the exceptions, is another sin altogether. But they can both be fixed by removing that try entirely.

Comment: I edited my code above and added the catch block, but still no exceptions are thrown?Not sure about the ```return null;``` though.

Comment: This answer does not address the question. If gives good tips about how to manage exceptions only.

Comment: @JohnCaprez The best answer possible is "do not hide Exceptions, they are your debugging infromation". Unless you know something I do not know, in wich case I would ask that you edit the question or link to that, to make it generally availible.